# Setting up stdlib path while compiling with mingw on linux

Tags: c++, mingw, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

I am trying to build my `c++` `CMake` project on linux with `mingw`. CMakeLists.txt consists of (for understanding):

- Setting up project info:

```
project(<project name> LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

- Setting up `TRY_COMPILE` target type:

```
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE "STATIC_LIBRARY")
```

- Setting up `boost`:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system program_options REQUIRED)
```

- Including subdirectories in which there is nothing about `mingw`:

```
add_subdirectory(<some_subdirectory>)
...
```

At the time of build process I see the following compilation command in the log:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++  -I/usr/include -I<user include 1> -I<user include 2> -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++20 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/common.dir/<source>.cpp.o -MF <source>.cpp.o.d -o <source>.cpp.o -c <project path>/<source>.cpp
```

After that goes a compiler error message with the following beginning:

```
[build] In file included from /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/12.2.0/cstdint:41,
[build]                  from /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:731,
[build]                  from /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/12.2.0/ios:40,
[build]                  from /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/12.2.0/ostream:38,
[build]                  from <project path>/<source>.hpp:5,
[build]                  from <project path>/<source>.cpp:1:
[build] /usr/include/stdint.h:90:33: error: conflicting declaration «typedef long unsigned int uintptr_t»
[build]    90 | typedef unsigned long int       uintptr_t;
[build]       |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
...
```

According to the internet this error message is connected with the different `mingw` standard library implementation.
I guess in a compile command there should somehow be `-I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include` on a place of `-I/usr/include` in a compilation command. If I am right there, the question is "How to change standard include directory for `mingw` build spicifically?". If I am not right there, then how to solve the problem with project building?

PS: The project builds using both `clang++` and `g++`.

Comment: `-I/usr/include` is problematic. MinGW has its own headers elsewhere, it'll be confused by those. Just remove it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I understrand. So how to change it?

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice CMake does it for you. Normally you write something called [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html), which sets the compiler path and restricts the header/library search to certain directories.

Comment: I can also recommend [quasi-msys2](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2), which has a CMake wrapper that handles this automatically, and also lets you download various prebuilt libraries for mingw (e.g. boost). (Full disclosure: I'm the author.)

Comment: If your code is open-source, I can try building it and provide complete instructions.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat My project is at https://github.com/gogagum/archiever and I am trying to compile from `dev` branch. I tried to write a toolchain file (mingw-w64-x86_64.cmake), and add `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=mingw-w64-x86_64.cmake` but it did not help.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat there is a submodule in the project (`git submodule init` & `git submodule update`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251964/discussion-between---and-holyblackcat).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat In fact, `-I/usr/include` was caused by incorrect `boost` found for `mingw` (defalult boost from `/usr/lib/cmake/Boost-1.81.0` was found and then Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS were set to `/usr/include`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two ways of solving the problem without additional tools.

## Installing special `boost` package for `MinGW`

First of all, to cross-compile project with `boost` it is good to have special package of `boost`. For me it was `mingw-w64-boost`:

```
> yay mingw-w64-boost
```

Then I had to set `BOOST_ROOT` to `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/` before `find_package(...)` or set `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` manually (again, to `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/`).

## Including `boost` from sources

It is also possible to add `boost` modules directly from `github`:

```
function(add_boost_package PackageName package_repo_addr tag)
    message(STATUS "FetchContent: ${PackageName}, ${package_repo_addr}, ${tag}")

    FetchContent_Declare(
        ${PackageName}
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/boostorg/${package_repo_addr}.git
        GIT_TAG ${tag}
    )

    FetchContent_MakeAvailable(${PackageName})
endfunction()

SET(BOOST_FETCHCONTENT_TAG boost-1.81.0)

add_boost_package(Boost.Core core ${BOOST_FETCHCONTENT_TAG})
add_boost_package(Boost.Config config ${BOOST_FETCHCONTENT_TAG})
add_boost_package(Boost.Assert assert ${BOOST_FETCHCONTENT_TAG})
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) for your cross-compiler.

---

But I'd suggest using [quasi-msys2](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2), which takes care of this, and also gives you access to prebuilt libraries for MinGW (Boost in your case).

- Install dependencies (this assumes Ubuntu, for other distributions adjust as needed)

  ```bash
  # Install Clang and LLD
  bash -c "$(wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh)"
  # Install other dependencies
  sudo apt install make wget tar zstd gpg wine
  ```
- Install and run quasi-msys2:

  ```bash
  git clone https://github.com/holyblackcat/quasi-msys2
  cd quasi-msys2/
  make install _gcc _boost
  env/shell.sh
  cd ..
  ```
- Now build your repo:

  ```bash
  git clone https://github.com/gogagum/archiever
  cd archiever/
  git checkout dev
  git submodule update --init --recursive

  cmake -B build/
  cmake --build build/ -j4
  ```
- I tried running the test app too:

  ```bash
  cd build/numerical/
  ./numerical_encoder.exe --input-file Makefile # This uses Wine automatically
  ```

Comment: make install command failed (see issue: https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2/issues/3)

Comment: @ГеоргийГуминов Hmm, I'll look into it tomorrow. Perhaps something changed in Make 4.4, I'm still sitting at 4.3.

Comment: @ГеоргийГуминов Should be fixed now, please try again. `rm -rf quasi-msys2` and clone it again.